# How to use onActivityResult twice in one Activity

Tags: android, onactivityresult

`error:method onActivityResult(int,int, Intent) is already defined in class scan.`

So I'm trying to build an app where u snap a photo and than the app detects text on the photo. Sadly I use the method `onActivityResult` twice.
Since I'm new to coding and in general a bit stupid, I don't know how to solve this.

adding the number 1 behind the ints where I first used them, but well that didn't do it

```
private void camera(){
    Intent intent2 = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent2, 0);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode1, int resultCode1 , Intent data1) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode1,resultCode1,data1);
    if (resultCode1==RESULT_OK){
        Bitmap btp = (Bitmap) data1.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(btp);
    }
}

public void detect (View v){
    if (bitmap == null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bitmap is null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        FirebaseVisionImage firebaseVisionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap);
        FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer firebaseVisionTextRecognizer = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getOnDeviceTextRecognizer();
        firebaseVisionTextRecognizer.processImage(firebaseVisionImage)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseVisionText>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText) {
                        process_text(firebaseVisionText);
                    }
                });

    }

}

private void process_text(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText) {
    List<FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock> blocks = firebaseVisionText.getTextBlocks();
    if (blocks.size() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"no text detected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        for (FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock block:firebaseVisionText.getTextBlocks()){
            String text = block.getText();
            textView.setText(text);
        }
    }
}

public void pick_image(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i,1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),uri);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

error: method onActivityResult(int,int,Intent) is already defined in class scan

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two very different languages, even though they both have "java" in their names. Please don't use the JavaScript tag when you're really referring to Java.

Comment: no need for multiple onActivityResult, change your request code for every activity you start and onActivityResult you can check the request code.

Comment: I'm sorry @Zoe 
I'll use it corectly in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to put it in one `onActivityResult`.

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),uri);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        Bitmap btp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(btp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define request code inside your class

`static final int REQUEST_PHOTO_1 = 1;
static final int REQUEST_PHOTO_2 = 2;`

Then while calling use

```
startActivityForResult(intent1, REQUEST_PHOTO_1);
startActivityForResult(intent2, REQUEST_PHOTO_2);
```

Now, in onActivityResult you can do something like this.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if(requestCode == REQUEST_PHOTO_1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
{
    ....
}
else if(requestCode == REQUEST_PHOTO_2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
{
    ....
}
else if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
    Bitmap btp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    imageView.setImageBitmap(btp);
}
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I used @Jakobs solution. But thank you for ur answer, time

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [at the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) and [the reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)).

The second parameter of `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)` is a request code, that will be passed as the first parameter of `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`.

Example:

```java
private void camera(){
    Intent intent2 = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent2, 0);
}

public void pick_image(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        switch(requestCode){
            case 0: // handle camera
                Bitmap btp = (Bitmap) data1.getExtras().get("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(btp);
            break;
            case 1: // handle pick_image
               Uri uri = data.getData();
               try {
                   bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
                   imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
               } catch (IOException e){
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

As the documentation shows, you should refactor the request codes into class constants for better readability and easier understanding.